# Django testrunner not working properly

Tags: python, django, django-testing

the following code:

```
class CreateSurveyFromCsvTextTests(TestCase):

    def test_parses_survey_passed_in_as_csv_and_returns_xml_representation(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

throws the following error:

```
ERROR: test_parses_survey_passed_in_as_csv_and_returns_xml_representation (dkobo.formbuilder.tests.CreateSurveyFromCsvTextTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nico/.virtualenvs/kf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 178, in __call__
    self._pre_setup()
  File "/home/nico/.virtualenvs/kf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 749, in _pre_setup
    self._fixture_setup()
  File "/home/nico/.virtualenvs/kf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 861, in _fixture_setup
    if not connections_support_transactions():
  File "/home/nico/.virtualenvs/kf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 848, in connections_support_transactions
    for conn in connections.all())
  File "/home/nico/.virtualenvs/kf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 848, in <genexpr>
    for conn in connections.all())
  File "/home/nico/.virtualenvs/kf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/nico/.virtualenvs/kf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 664, in supports_transactions
    self.connection.leave_transaction_management()
  File "/home/nico/.virtualenvs/kf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 317, in leave_transaction_management
    if managed == self.get_autocommit():
  File "/home/nico/.virtualenvs/kf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 324, in get_autocommit
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/nico/.virtualenvs/kf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 124, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/nico/.virtualenvs/kf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 86, in __exit__
    db_exc_type = getattr(self.wrapper.Database, dj_exc_type.__name__)
AttributeError: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'Database'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I know this doesn't tell you much about the problem, and it's probably an environment problem, but I'm new to Linux/Python (switched from Windows/.Net 7 days ago) and wouldn't really know where to start gathering information, let alone diagnosing the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django testrunner throws 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'Database' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181241/django-testrunner-throws-databasewrapper-object-has-no-attribute-database-er)

Comment: Opening another question with the same issue won't get it answered faster. As such I've voted to close this one. Someone may answer that other question if they know the answer.

Comment: @SimeonVisser It's not the same question, the other question assumed there was something wrong with the code being tested (the test body actually does something). Later I found out that the tested code isn't even invoked, and the test fails with an obviously true assertion

Comment: @SimeonVisser and I already deleted the other question... and would really appreciate some help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the database was not configured. Adding the default entry for `DATABASE` in `settings.py` and the running `python manage.py syncdb` fixed it.